# Struggling to understand reduce on TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, overloading, reduce

Let's say I define a Utility type to have an object with all attributes as string

```js
type Stringify<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: string;
};
```

and I want to define a function that converts any attribute of an object to string such as

```js
function stringify<T>(obj: T): Stringify<T> {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
        acc[k] = `${v}`;
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

I can't figure out how to define the accumulator that is being fulfilled at every cicle in the reduce callback

```js
.reduce<Partial<T>>((acc, [k, v]) => /* ... */) // type Partial<T> is not assignable to type Stringify<T>
.reduce((acc: Partial<T>, [k, v]) => /* ... */) // type Partial<T> is not assignable to type Stringify<T>
.reduce(/* ... */, {} as Partial<T>) // type Partial<T> is not assignable to type Stringify<T>

.reduce(/* ...*/
  acc[k] = `${v}`; // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Stringify<T>'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Stringify<T>'
}, {} as Stringify<T>)
```

I've been reading about casting, type guards, and function overload but I still can't arrive to a solution to such a simple example.

Comment: Does this work? - `acc[k as keyof T] = \`${v}\`;`

Comment: It seems to work. Thank! Is that just enough? I sometimes feel I spend more time fixing TypeScript typing errors (that I don't know if are properly applied) rather than developping my business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Stringify` generic is essentially doing the same job as the utility type `Record`.

You can use the generic argument to act as a shorthand for `Record<string, any>` to save a bit of verbosity.

```
function stringify<T = Record<string, any>>(obj: T): T {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
        return { ...acc, [k] : `${v}` }
    }, {} as T);
}
```

Update: typing return value as Record<string, string>

```
function stringify<T = Record<string, any>, R = Record<string, string>>(obj: T): R {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
        return { ...acc, [k] : `${v}` }
    }, {} as R);
}

const a = stringify({ a: 1, b: 2})

console.log(a)
```

Comment: I'm afraid Record<string, any> does not accomplish the requirements for the proposed scenario. Return type must have the exact same keys as input but values must be strings.

Comment: Answer updated to deal with return requirement